# If both select values have been selected run function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to populate and show a `select` if the previous 12 dropdowns have a value.

I cant seem to get my if statement correct though, can anybody see what I may be doing wrong?

```
$('select').on('change',function(){

if( $('.player1') != null || $('.player2') != null ){

    // If both players have been selected, show the winner dropdown and populate it with the value from player1 and player 2.
    $('.winner').show();

}

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kbPLn/1/

Comment: How can a dropdown in your example hasnt a value?

Comment: I want that dropdown to take the value of whatever has been selected in the previous 2 dropdowns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the cases you have will never be null.. (as youre not checking .val...and also, they always have a val) updated your HTML + your selectors here:

http://jsfiddle.net/kbPLn/5/

```
if( $('.player1>option:selected').val() != "No value" && $('.player2>option:selected').val() != "No value" ){
```

**updated**
http://jsfiddle.net/kbPLn/9/

```
        var first = $('.player1>option:selected').val(),
         second =$('.player2>option:selected').val();

        $('.winner').find('option:first').val(first).html(first);
        $('.winner').find('option:not(:first)').val(second).html(second);
        $('.winner').show();
```

Comment: Ahh thanks @JFit, is it possible to then set the selected values from the first 2 dropdowns and then populate the 2nd select with those?

Answer (score 1):

A jQuery object will never equal `null`. What you can do is check the `length` property of the collection. Also, it looks like you want `&&` instead of `||`.

```
if ($('.player1>option:selected').length && $('.player2>option:selected').length) {
```

EDIT: What you rather need to do is check if it has a selected child option.

Comment: should be `$('.player1>option:selected').length` *the elements youre checking there will always have length = 1..

Comment: Oops. :P I'll fix that.

Comment: You should probally delete your comment also with the "or so you assume" part.. makes you kinda look like a bollocks :/ lol :P

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `&&` when checking negation values

Answer (score 0):

```
 Try this. This may help you:
 $('select').on('change', function () {
            $('select[name="winner"]').html('');
            if ($('.player1') != null || $('.player2') != null) {

                // If both players have been selected, show the winner dropdown and populate it with the value from player1 and player 2.
                $('.winner').show();

                //$('.winner').
            }
            $('select[name="winner"]').append('<option value="' + $(".player1").val() + '">' + $(".player1").val() + '</option>');
            $('select[name="winner"]').append('<option value="' + $(".player2").val() + '">' + $(".player2").val() + '</option>');
        });
```